# IllegalArgumentException в Android 4.3

Tags: android

Есть 2 приложения (А и Б). У А есть функционал по забору данных из Б при помощи ContentProvider:

```
public void importFromB()
{
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://" + Config.APP_B_PATH + ".myContentProvider");
    Cursor cursor = _context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    ...
}
```

На версиях Android ниже 4.3 все замечательно работает и доступ к данным приложение А получает. Но на 4.3 на строке получения курсора кидает исключение:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI not supported: content://com.myapp.appb.myContentProvider
```

Перечитал доки гугла, перерыл инет и ничего не нашел. Может кто встречался с подобным и смог побороть?

Comment: там есть разные уровни доступа к контент провайдеру. Может поменялись?

Answer (score 2):

Как верно сказал [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim):

> `<provider>`
>
> `android:exported`
>
> Whether the content provider is
> available for other applications to
> use: true: The provider is available
> to other applications. Any application
> can use the provider's content URI to
> access it, subject to the permissions
> specified for the provider. false: The
> provider is not available to other
> applications. Set
> android:exported="false" to limit
> access to the provider to your
> applications. Only applications that
> have the same user ID (UID) as the
> provider will have access to it.
>
> **The
> default value is "true" for
> applications that set either
> android:minSdkVersion or
> android:targetSdkVersion to "16" or
> lower. For applications that set
> either of these attributes to "17" or
> higher, the default is "false".**

Вам требуется явно установить `android:exported` в `true`.

Comment: я думаю, это абсолютно правильный ответ.

Comment: В том то и дело, что этот атрибут у меня выставлен в true